# Как из php файла передать данные в переменную javascript

Tags: php, javascript, api, yandex-maps-api

Через API получаю данные от стороннего сервиса. Структура ответа:

```
[ { 
        ...     
        “Latitude”: “<Широта>”,
        “Longitude”:    “<Долгота>”,
        ...
} ]
```

С помощью php файла getdata.php прохожу по массиву и собираю все данные

```
foreach ($response as $item) {
    $a = "[".$item['Latitude'].",".$item['Longitude']."]," ;   
    $array = $array.$a ;
}

    $list= substr($array, 0, -1);
    echo json_encode($list);
```

Это список точек, который я хочу отобразить на карте с помощью Яндекс.Карты API.

```
var myMap = new ymaps.Map('map', {
...
    points = [
        [55.831903,37.411961], [55.763338,37.565466]
    ],
}
```

1. Как мне передать данные переменной **$list** в **points**?
2. Вопрос по корректности кода в php? Он вроде выводит верные данные, но нужно ли делать **json_encode** и можно ли заменить **substr($array, 0, -1);** на что-то внутри **foreach**?

Comment: если код js и php в одном файле можно сделать так : `var value = <?php echo $string;?>`

Comment: да. это я знаю. поэтому я и написал, что они в разных файлах

Comment: сделайте аякс запрос в getdata.php, и передайте те данные которы вам нужны.

Comment: function showData(){
               $.ajax({
                url: "/getdata.php",
                data: "",
                dataType: 'json',
                success: {    points = $list                  
                }
              });
              return false;
        } - так это работает?

Comment: да , только синтаксис поправте.
 а почему вы в функции возвращаете false?

Comment: Не нужно так конструировать строку, просто массив переводите в json с помощью json_encode.

Comment: @UrmuzTagizade ваш ответ создал еще больше ответов. Я, с моим уровнем, не увидел там ответа

Comment: @GinoPane а на какой вопрос вы ответили?

Comment: На ваш:) Не нужно делать это: `$a = "[".$item['Latitude'].",".$item['Longitude']."]," ;   
    $array = $array.$a ;`. Всё это может сделать сам PHP автоматически функцией `json_encode`.

Comment: тогда не понимаю как получить именно эти данные из ответа, чтобы из большого массива сделать массив только с Latitude и Longitude

Answer (score 1):

сделайте аякс запрос на ваш файл:

```
 function shaowData(){
var data = '';
   $.ajax({
     url: урл на getdata.php,
     dataType: 'json',
     async:false,
     success: function(response) {
       var data = response;
     }
    });

   return data;
  }

  var points = showData();  // это будет ваш массив, дальше вставляете его куда вам нужно
```

в файле getdata.php

```
  `foreach ($response as $item) {
$a = "[".$item['Latitude'].",".$item['Longitude']."]," ;   
$array = $array.$a ;
 }

$list= substr($array, 0, -1);
echo json_encode($list);`
```

Comment: вместо response можно использовать переменную $list? а как ее данные присвоить в js переменную points?

Comment: в файле getdata делаете `echo $list`, а после запроса response будет вашим массивом

Comment: `success: function(response) {
       где response ваш массив с данными.
     }`
тут не понимаю что писать и как присваивать значение переменной $list. пишу: 
    `function showData() { 
        $.ajax({ 
            url: "/PickpointapiYaMapGetPostamatlist.php", 
            data: "", 
            dataType: 'json', 
            success: function(response) {
                var response = $list
            }
        }); 
    } `
пишет Uncaught ReferenceError: $list is not defined

Comment: @angelzzz, нет же , после запроса response и есть ваш $list, console.log(response), сделайте в функции success, если всё правильно вы увидите ваш массив

Comment: консоль лог выводит данные. а как теперь их передать в переменную points вот тут `var myMap = new ymaps.Map('map', {
...
    points = [
        [55.831903,37.411961], [55.763338,37.565466]
    ],
}`

Comment: я вызываю так эту функцию `ymaps.ready(function () {
    showData()
    var myMap = new ymaps.Map('map', { ... points = points = [
            response
        ],, }`

Comment: @angelzzz, смотрите в ответ, я написал как нужно сделать , а вообще почитайте документацию по ajax  http://jquery.page2page.ru/index.php5/Ajax-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41893/discussion-between-angelzzz-and-bogdan-gudyma).